# Date object is valid in Chrome but not Safari, Firefox, or IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs, date-formatting

I am fetching a date object from an API. Here's the format returned from the API:

"2016-04-05 13:39:46.612"

Chrome seems to interpret this and display it correctly, but in Firefox, Safari, and IE, I get either null or invalid date.

**Chrome results:**

```
console.log(purchaseDate) 
>> Tue Apr 05 2016 13:39:46 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

This HTML in Angular view: {{$scope.purchaseDate | date:'MMM d, y h:mm a'}}
outputs: Apr 5, 2016 1:39 PM

**Firefox results (similar for Safari and IE):**

```
console.log(purchaseDate) 
>> Invalid Date
```

This HTML in Angular view: {{$scope.purchaseDate | date:'MMM d, y h:mm a'}}
outputs: null

I've tried formatting the date using moment.js before sending it to the browser (as suggested in answers to similar questions), but the results aren't much better:

**Chrome results:**

```
console.log(moment(purchaseDate).format()) 
>> 2016-04-05T13:39:46-05:00
```

**Firefox results (similar for Safari and IE):**

```
console.log(moment(purchaseDate).format()) 
>> Invalid Date
```

Any ideas? I'd like to use moment.js to get the parsing consistent, since I'm already using it elsewhere in my code.

Comment: You should pass the format to *moment.js* in the first call, otherwise it's just guessing when parsing the string.

Comment: If that's really the format coming as a string directly from the API, then go back to the API and change it to something sensible like ISO-8601.  However, my guess is that you have already parsed the API result into a `Date` object and you're actually looking at the implicit conversion of `Date` to `string`.  Are you *sure* that's the exact string coming out of the API?  Look at the raw HTTP.

Comment: Can you influence on what your API returns? If yes the best solution would be NOT return data in this format, it's pretty crazy.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `purchaseDate`?

Comment: Good call, @MattJohnson, the raw response is actually "2016-04-05 13:39:46.612". I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue and for me the best solution was to use momentjs library to parse the date string:

```
bower install --save moment
```

and then for example:

```
 $scope.purchaseDate  = moment("2016-04-05 13:39:46.612", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS").toDate();
```

see parsing format here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

in the HTML page for example:

```
{{purchaseDate | date:'medium'}}
```

**beware that momentjs takes care of your local timezone and will the date accordingly change**

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this exact thing and am still getting null/invalid date in browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: I got your point, please try: $scope.purchaseDate  = moment("2016-04-05 13:39:46.612", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS").toDate();

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use moment with angular, you should also use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

When loading your value, create a `moment` object instead of a `Date` object.

```
var purchaseDate = moment("2016-04-05 13:39:46.612");
```

This particular format is already recognized by moment.js, so you don't need to provide a format string when parsing.  Though do be aware that it will be interpreted as *local* time.  If you wanted it in UTC instead, then:

```
var purchaseDate = moment.utc("2016-04-05 13:39:46.612");
```

Either way, you can then use angular-moment to format it:

```
{{$scope.purchaseDate | amDateFormat:'MMM D, Y h:mm a'}}
```

Angular-moment also provide lots of other filters you can use if you like.  [Check out their docs](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I believe angular moment converts strings to moments for you. No need to preprocess. Haven't used it in a long time though, so don't quote me on it.

Comment: @MaggiePint - Good point.  It can parse the string directly.  I think it will work with a moment object or date object as well, but haven't tested in awhile.

Comment: Reading the source code, it looks like it just passes directly to the moment constructor in this use case. So, string, moment, date, integer in milliseconds, and ASP.NET ugly date string should all work. You have to do something else if you have integer in seconds though.